# Update CosmosDB Shard collection using C#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I was trying to update document in CosmosDB using C# MS Azure DocumentDB Core.

Below code worked fine for non Shard collection and failed for Shard collection, which is production scenario for data storage of more than 10 GB. For Shard collection, shard key was defined on "Demographics.Address.Country" field.

```
var builder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<CustomerDO>();
    var filter = builder.Eq("Id", customer.Id);

FieldDefinition<CustomerDO, Demographics> field1 = "Demographics";
var update = Builders<CustomerDO>.Update
                   .Set(field1, customer.Demographics);
Collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Above code fails for shard collection with Error-

> Command update failed: query in command must target a single shard
>   key.

I found issue in update code.
Update operation worked with addition of Shard Key in Filter Definition expression-

```
var filter = builder.Eq("Id", customer.Id) & builder.Eq("Demographics.Address.Country", "IND");
```

Comment: it's trying so say  "hey this could affect > 1 record so I'm not going to allow it".  You need to use the unique id for the doc.  customer.id may not be good enough...

Comment: hi John, Thanks for reply. I have customer.Id as unique identifier for document, mapped to "_id" field of CosmosDB MongoDB API.

Comment: i see.  well it remains true that your update is causing some sort of affect on more than one record - re-examine the schema?

Comment: what is the `Shard Key` in this example?

Comment: Hi John, I have customer.Demographics.Address.Country as shard key

Comment: Update worked with addition of Shard Key in Filter Definition -                                var filter = builder.Eq("Id", customer.Id) & builder.Eq("Demographics.Address.Country", "IND");